# Trying to get logging to work with slf4j, IKVM / IKVM.Maven.Sdk - how to set class path?

Tags: c#, maven, slf4j, ikvm

I'm having problems with IKVM.Maven.SDK - to simplify things, I created a basic .Net 6.0 console app that uses slf4j to log "Hello World" - as per https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html, but in .Net.

Despite adding MavenReferences to `org.slf4j:slf4j-api` and `org.slf4j:slf4j-simple`, I still get the warnings:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
```

slf4j.org says "This warning is printed because no slf4j provider (or binding) could be found on your class path."

How do I set class path with IKVM / IKVM.Maven.SDK?

My csproj file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IKVM.Maven.Sdk" Version="1.5.5" />
    <MavenReference Include="org.slf4j:slf4j-api" Version="2.0.9" />
    <MavenReference Include="org.slf4j:slf4j-simple" Version="2.0.9" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

My Program.cs file:

```cs
using org.slf4j;

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("IkvmLogTests");
logger.info("Hello, World!");
```

I tried adding a user environment variable set to where Maven is downloading

`$env:CLASSPATH: C:\Users\matt\.m2\repository`

And on build in Visual Studio that directory does get populated with the jar files for slf4j-api and slf4j-simple, (for example for slf4j-api the file `C:\Users\matt\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.9\slf4j-api-2.0.9.jar` is there).

I tried adding

```xml
<PackageReference Include="IKVM" Version="8.6.2" />
```

But no change to result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to preload any dynamic assemblies (thanks to a response from [wasabii](https://github.com/wasabii) on github, one of the main sponsors/contributors to IKVM.Maven.Sdk)

```cs
using org.slf4j;

// preload logging provider
Assembly.Load("slf4j.simple");

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("IkvmLogTests");
logger.info("Hello, World!");
```